# In R exclude character in string when shorter version exists

Tags: r, regex, grepl

The data is a toy example.  Each character in `have` has letters.  I want to exclude characters if a shorter character includes n-1 of the letters.
For example, ADB is excluded because we have AB. ADE is kept because we don't have AD AE or DE.

```
have <- c('A,B', 'B,C', 'A,D,B', 'A,B,E', 'A,D,E')
want <- c('A,B', 'B,C', 'A,D,E')
```

I know that `grepl` may be useful but I'm not sure how to do this in a computationally efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way by splitting the string.

```
#Split the string on comma
tmp <- strsplit(have, ',')
#Iterate over the index of tmp
have[!sapply(seq_along(tmp), function(x) {
  one <- tmp[[x]]
  any(sapply(tmp[-x], function(y) sum(one %in% y)) >= (length(one) - 1) & 
      lengths(tmp[-x]) < length(one))
})]

#[1] "A,B"   "B,C"   "A,D,E"
```

- `sum(one %in% y)` counts how many characters of current string are present in another string.
- `>= (length(one) - 1)` ensures `n-1 of the letters` condition.
- `lengths(tmp[-x]) < length(one)` ensures that it is shorter.